# Book reference for proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

> A finite group characteristically simple is isomorphic to a direct product of simple groups.

Does anyone know of a book that contains this proof? I just need to reference it, but in the books I've been looking for, I have not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rotman, [An Introduction to the Theory of Groups](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387942858), 4th edition, theorem 5.26.

Comment: Thank you! ${}$